# Why won't this swap macro compile?

Tags: c

The K&R 2nd ed answer book has the following solution for a variable argument swap macro

```
#define swap(t, x, y) { t _z; \   
                       _z = y; \ 
                       y = x; \  
                       x = _z; }
```

Visual Studio Express is telling me that y and x must be constant values and that there is an "expected declaration" to the left of the right brace.

Is this formatting out of date?

Edit:

The way that code is formatted won't let me compile for the errors listed above, but the following code seems to be fine:

```
#define swap(t, x, y) { t _z; _z = y; y = x; x = _z; }
```

Comment: How do you invoke it? Did you try `swap(int,xx,yy);` after `int xx,yy;` ?

Comment: How are you using the macro? It should be `swap(int, a, b)`

Comment: I haven't even compiled anything. It won't let me compile it because there are the errors I posted above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is you have whitespace after the `\` line continuation characters. As such, the `\` is no longer treated as a line continuation, but just a non-whitespace character. This means the following lines are *not* part of the macro definition, and the compiler tries to compile them as normal lines. Getting rid of the whitespace after each `\` will fix the error.